# Adding functionality to the activity (inheritance, decoration, strategy ... )

Tags: android, oop, inheritance, android-fragments, strategy-pattern

I cannot decide what approach  should I use in the next situtation.

One activity from my app need to have different functionality, here is the leak of multiple inheritence comes into play.

What I need to get ?

There are several parts that my activity has to have.

1. Navigation drawer. I am using [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library. It requires activity to implement on click callbacks (or use composition instead), but also it use activity as constructor argument,so  I think it will be better to put this into separate class inherited from Activity or any base class provided by Android  Framework . Thanks to library developer it doesn't require any stuff to be done in on create method ( setContentLayout for instance)
2. My activity(one of several) will have only Toolbar and FrameLayout for holding fragment . Or it is better to separate toolbar and single fragment  ?
   This in turn requires some stuff to be done in onCreate : setContentLayout with basic layout , add fragment to the container set activity actionbar .....
3. Maybe in future I will use another libraries that requires to add something in activity lifecycle methods.

All these points in order to follow Single Responsibility principle have to be separate classes inherited from some base Activity.
For example we will have something like this.

```
public class SingleFragmentActivity<T extends Fragment> extends AppCompatActivity {

}
public class SingleFragmentToolbarActivity<T extends Fragment> extends AppCompatActivity {

}
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

}
....
```

As you can see each functionality is put into the separate class, but what if I need to have `SingleFramgentActivity` with `NavigationDrawer` ?
In this case I have to inherit one of these classes from another, for example

```
public class NavigationDrawer extends SingleFragmentActivity {

}
```

If to do so, I have no ability to use navigation drawer separately from `SingleFragmentActivity`.

What is the best practice to follow in this case, how to build class hierarchy to make it flexible and use Open-Close principle, to make changes in application without any pain. (Use strategy, decorator ..... ?)

I would be grateful everyone for help.